# Why is the code giving error for certain object properties?

Tags: javascript, loops

A lookUpProfile function that takes name and a property (prop) as arguments has been pre-written for you.

The function should check if name is an actual contact's firstName and the given property (prop) is a property of that contact.

If both are true, then return the "value" of that property.

If name does not correspond to any contacts then return "No such contact"

If prop does not correspond to any valid properties of a contact found to match name then return "No such property"

```
//Setup
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];  


function lookUpProfile(name, prop){
// Only change code below this line
 for(var i = 0; i < contacts.length;i++){
  if(name === contacts[i].firstname ){
    if(contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
      return contacts[i][prop];
    }else {
      return "No such property";
    }
  }
}
return "No such contact";

// Only change code above this line
}

// Change these values to test your function
lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes");
```

"Kristian", "lastName" should return "Vos"
"Sherlock", "likes" should return ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
"Harry","likes" should return an array
"Akira", "address" should return "No such property"

Comment: `firstname !== firstName`

Comment: You have just dumped the problem statement and code from either your [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823) or some coding challenge. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `if(name === contacts[i].firstname )` this condition with `if(name === contacts[i].firstName )` this one. You have mistakenly used `firstname` instead of `firstName`.

javascript is case sensitive and it will treat `firstname` and `firstName` as two different variables